# New column in pandas DataFrame conditional on value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country' : ['US','FR','DE','SP'], 
    'energy_per_capita': [10,8,9,7], 
    'pop_2014' : [300,70,80,60],
    'pop_2015': [305,72,80,'NaN']})
```

I'd like to create a new column:

```
df['total energy consumption']
```

which multiplies energy_per_capita and pop.
I'd like it to take pop_2015 when available and pop_2014 if pop_2015 == NaN

thanks

Comment: I'd like for you to be able to create that column, too! So what have you tried?

Comment: I'm very new to Python and programming in general...
I've tried to calculate it based on a if / else statement but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you read [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). For this case we are using [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country' : ['US','FR','DE','SP'], 
    'energy_per_capita': [10,8,9,7], 
    'pop_2014' : [300,70,80,60],
    'pop_2015': [305,72,80,np.nan]})

df['total energy consumption']= df['energy_per_capita'] *df['pop_2015'].fillna(df['pop_2014'])
print df
```

output

```
  country  energy_per_capita  pop_2014  pop_2015  total energy consumption
0      US                 10       300     305.0                    3050.0
1      FR                  8        70      72.0                     576.0
2      DE                  9        80      80.0                     720.0
3      SP                  7        60       NaN                     420.0
```

Comment: I would do `df.pop_2015.combine_first(df.pop_2014)` that fits better the concept of "take a value from this column, but if NaN then here is the alternative one"